# Can't update image source in Kivy project

Tags: python, kivy

I want to change the image of a play/pause button (once to be 'play_icon.png' for play and once to be 'pause_icon.png'). The problem is that I am new to programming and I don't know why the image is not  updating. I have a class called Icon(Image) and the source image in it and I am changing the source image from the class KivyApp(App). When I print the source from KivyApp I see that it changes, but not the image on the button.

Here is some code from my project:

main.py

```
class Icon(Image):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Icon, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.source = 'play_icon.png'

class KivyApp(App):

    app = App.get_running_app()

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()

    def start_stop(self):
        if <condition>:
            Icon.source = 'pause_icon.png'
        else:
            Icon.source = 'play_icon.png'
```

kivy.kv

```
Button:
    id: btn
    on_press: app.start_stop()
    Icon:
        id: icon
        source: self.source
        size: self.parent.size
        x: self.parent.x
        y: self.parent.y
        keep_ratio: True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icon.source = 'pause_icon.png'

This is changing the `source` attribute of the `Icon` class, which doesn't have any effect at all on the instances of that class you have created.

You need to change the `source` attribute of the instance of the Icon class that you are displaying in your gui.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. Now I am trying to change the `source` attribute like this: `self.root.ids.mainpage.ids.btn.ids.icon.source = 'pause_icon.png'` and I am getting this error: `'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`.

Comment: It's likely that you're trying to access the ids before they exist. Try reversing it: use `source: app.source` then in the app class `source = StringProperty()`. You can then change `App.get_running_app().source` to have the change propagate to your widget instance.